# JSTL <c:if> tag to compare two variables

Tags: jstl

Why the block never reaches "conditionTrue"? I have printed both the variables 
authorEmail and  scase.authorEmail and they are same string. If I use literal like 'abc@yahoo.com' to test the condition , it works but not if both the c:if params are variables.

```
<c:forEach var="scase" items="${section.subSectionList.get(0).SCaseList}">

  <c:set var="authorEmail" >
      <sec:authentication property="principal.email" /> 
  </c:set>

  <c:if test = "${authorEmail == scase.authorEmail}" >
    <option>conditionTrue</option>
  </c:if>                                       

</c:forEach>
```

UPDATE - I got it to work by making these changes.

I commented out the entire c:set tag. Instead I added these line -

```
<sec:authentication var="principal" property="principal" />
```

My test condition was then :

```
 <c:if test = "${principal.email == scase.authorEmail}" >
     <option>conditionTrue</option>
  </c:if>
```

And this worked. However, the reasoning behind it still baffles me. Any insight, much appreciated.

Comment: You'd want to compare strings, not references to them. Use isEquals method of either authorEmail or scase.authorEmail. Good luck1

Comment: Your hardcoded abc@yahoo works because strings are interned in java server pages (and java code in general)

Comment: Please ignore the above nonsense of users who don't at all know how EL works.